# How to install numpy on Python 2.7 in virtualenv?

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenv

I'm trying to install `numpy` on `Python 2.7` in `virtualenv` (on Cygwin).
However, when I try to `import numpy`, I get an `ImportError`:

```
Administrator@Ron ~/python/virtualenv
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7.exe machine_learning
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7.exe
New python executable in /home/Administrator/python/virtualenv/machine_learning/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /home/Administrator/python/virtualenv/machine_learning/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Administrator@Ron ~/python/virtualenv
$ source machine_learning/bin/activate
(machine_learning)
Administrator@Ron ~/python/virtualenv
$ pip2 install numpy
Collecting numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.0
(machine_learning)
Administrator@Ron ~/python/virtualenv
$ python2 -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/Administrator/python/virtualenv/machine_learning/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/Administrator/python/virtualenv/machine_learning/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/Administrator/python/virtualenv/machine_learning/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/home/Administrator/python/virtualenv/machine_learning/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 20, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/home/Administrator/python/virtualenv/machine_learning/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/home/Administrator/python/virtualenv/machine_learning/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 30, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: No such file or directory
(machine_learning)
Administrator@Ron ~/python/virtualenv
```

**Any suggestion how to install numpy on Python 2.7 in virtualenv?**

Note:
Cygwin's Python3 version is 3.6, and seems that pypi numpy's is not yet ready for 3.6.

**Edit 1:**

In answer to [matzeri](https://superuser.com/users/468219/matzeri)'s comment, I uninstalled `numpy` from pip3 and pip2, and installed `numpy` for Python 3 and Python 2 from Cygwin's setup.exe.
Following are the errors I get for numpy when I try to import it afterwards:

```
$ python3 -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 20, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: No such file or directory

$ python2 -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 20, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `python2-numpy` with cygwin setup.
You don't need pip to install it.

`python2 -c "import numpy"` works for me.
As the issue seems on `lapack_lite` check that you have `/usr/lib/lapack/` on your path.

```
$ cygcheck -l liblapack0
/etc/profile.d/lapack0.csh
/etc/profile.d/lapack0.sh
/usr/lib/lapack/cygblas-0.dll
/usr/lib/lapack/cyglapack-0.dll


 $ cygcheck /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.dll | grep -v Windows
E:\cygwin64\lib\python2.7\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.dll
  E:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
  E:\cygwin64\lib\lapack\cyglapack-0.dll
    E:\cygwin64\bin\cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
    E:\cygwin64\bin\cyggfortran-3.dll
      E:\cygwin64\bin\cygquadmath-0.dll
    E:\cygwin64\bin\cygblas-0.dll
  E:\cygwin64\bin\libpython2.7.dll
```

Otherwise the lapack library will not be operative.

Comment: Alas, I tried installing with PIP after I got errors when I installed the package you suggested.

Comment: Which errors you had with python2-numpy ?

Comment: In answer to your question, I added _Edit 1_ to the OP.